# Norm Function On Euclidean Domain

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

While trying to prove that if $a^2+b^2$ is prime in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ then $a+bi$ is also prime, I start solution by defining a norm $N$: $\mathbb{Z}[i] \to \mathbb{Z}_+$ as $N(a+bi)=a^2+b^2$.

But my teacher consider it wrong by saying that we can't define this map on sets other then Euclidean Domain.

And I don't understand why?

Comment: Ex falso quodlibet: $a^2 + b^2$ is never prime in ${\mathbb Z}[i]$.

Comment: You can always define an $N$. The hard part is defining it so that you get use from it. Your professor may be referring to the fact that if we are working in a Euclidean domain, then we already _know_ a load of useful facts it has. The points below by lhf illustrate how your $N$ could be useful for what you want to prove, regardless of what general property that the ring $\Bbb Z[i]$ fulfills or doesn't.

Comment: Your professor is  wrong: a `norm` map is defined on every finite field extension.

Comment: Thankyou everyone your answers give me a lot of confidence on my effort. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're in the right direction despite what your teacher says.

You now need to prove these properties for $N$:

- $N(\alpha \beta) = N(\alpha) N(\beta)$
- $N(\alpha) = 1$ iff $\alpha$ is a unit in $\mathbb Z[i]$

Finally, make sure you see how what you want to prove follows from these properties.