# Primes in Quadratic Extensions $K$ of the Ring $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, arithmetic

While studying Arithmetics, I came across an interesting theorem on the properties of primes in a quadratic extension $K$ of the ring $\mathbb{Z}$.
The theorem writes as follows:

> Let $x\in K$. If $N(x)$ is prime, then $x$ is prime.

The provided proof of the theorem states:

> Suppose that $x=yz$, $y,z\in K$. (If $N(x)$ is prime) Then $N(x)=N(y)N(z)$, so at least one of $N(y)$, $N(z)$ equals $\pm1$, i.e. either $y$ or $z$ is a unit, while the other one is (by definition) adjoint to $x$.

---

However, this theorem doesn't appear to make sense to me due to the following points:

- Firstly, for a nonunit, nonzero number $x\in K$ to be prime, its only divisors must be the units of $K$ and elements adjoint to itself.
- Secondly, by definition, $N(x)=x\overline{x}$.
- Lastly, given that $N(x)$ is always the product of two other numbers in $K$, how can it be that $N(x)$ is ever a prime? For every prime $x$, $N(x)$ cannot be prime, as $x$ is one of its divisors, right?

I'm very confused by this Theorem and would appreciate some insight on it. Thanks! :)

Comment: The condition is $N(x)$ is a prime in $\mathbb{Z}$, not the overring, so $N(x)=x\bar{x}$ does not necessarily say anything about primality of $N(x)$ in $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: So, for example, given that $N(1+i)=2$, I could infer from this theorem that, since 2 is prime in $\mathbb{Z}$, so is $1+i$ in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$?

Comment: Yes, indeed, $1+i$ is prime, because its norm is a prime number in $\Bbb Z$. Have a look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2609208/1i-is-prime-in-mathbb-zi), and at many similar posts.

Comment: The close votes here are very bizarre.  In what way does this question need more focus??

Comment: The argument is flawed, but for another reason: irreducible does not imply prime, even in quadratic integer rings.